# (Un)pivoting tables on SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to create a matrix with historical data for some parameters I have in a table. The matter is, when I try to pivot it, won't work. Using the following code

```
    SELECT concept,
        [1] '1993', 
        <...>,
        [23] '2015'
    FROM
        (SELECT concept, YEAR(begin_date) as year, value
         FROM params p WITH(NOLOCK)) AS st
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(value)
        FOR year IN ([1], <...>, [23])
    ) AS pt
```

will return nothing but a matrix full of NULL values. On the other hand, I've got the correct values using this other query

```
    SELECT pt.year 'Year', 
        [1], 
        <...>,
        [38]
    FROM 
        (SELECT concept, YEAR(begin_date) as year, value
        FROM parameters p WITH(NOLOCK)) AS st
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(value)
        FOR concept IN ([1], <...>, [38])
    ) AS pt
```

But then the columns and rows are supposed to be the other way around.
What could be the cause of this situation? How could it be solved?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
year IN ([1], <...>, [23])
```

This is probably supposed to be

```
year IN ([1993], <...>, [2015])
```

And then of course those same columns in the select part too:

```
SELECT concept,
    [1993], 
    <...>,
    [2015]
```

Comment: Worked simply perfect! Hard to believe the problem was that clear and haven't found it before... Thanks a lot!